# Fails to read the value of formular after using xlsxwriter to close and then usinging xlrd to read the excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlsxwriter

At fisrt, I use xlsxwriter to write a simple formula in one cell and close the *.xlsx file. Then I try to read the value of the cell but only read '0' from the cell using xlrd at the same program.

If I read some fixed values (like string or constant number) in a cell, it works well. 
If I create a formula cell manually in a *.xlsx file, the xlrd can also  get the value of the formula.

It seems that I cannot read the value of formula cell only when I write a forumla to *.xlsx and then read it in the same program.

Python: 3.4.3
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: 0.9.3

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

name = 'abc.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'sheet1'
# write a formula in 'D1' as '=A1+C1'
out_book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(name, {'im_memory': True})
out_sheet = out_book.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
out_sheet.write('A1', 1)
out_sheet.write('C1', 2)
out_sheet.write_formula(0, 3, '=A1+C1')
out_book.close()

#After closing excel, read the cell 
tmp = xlrd.open_workbook(name)
sheet = tmp.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
#show '2.0'
print (sheet.cell_value(0, 2))
#show '0.0'
print (sheet.cell_value(0, 3))
```

The result is :
2.0
0.0

But I expect it to be:
2.0
3.0

How can I solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use 'xlwing' to do both write and read: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks Trimax. Are you sure that xlwing can do first write formula and then read the value? I will try xlwing later

Answer (score 0):

XlsxWriter doesn't write the value of a formula to Excel. See the [Formula Result](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-result) section of the docs.

Comment: Hi Jmcnamara, I know it. But why can I read the final value of formula in excel if the formula is manually writen in excel?

Comment: Because Excel calculates the value of the formula and writes it to the file.

Comment: Thanks jmcnamara. You are right! But I really need the function that first writing a formula to Excel and then read the value from excel by programming. I will try xlwings or openpyxl later.

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to use some library that calls Excel (or another spreadsheet application) directly to calculate the result of the formula. Xlwings should be able to do that but openpyxl, and xlwt, behave the same way as XlsxWriter and do not perform any cacluations.