# Why would Pandas return blank cells after the dataframe is saved by Openpyxl?

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

I have a large data set that I pull into pandas with read-excel. I use the data to create a new column then write the new column to Excel with openpyxl. The issue is that if I read that file again, the original data will be read as blank values. The only way around this I have found so far is to re-write the original array. Why does this happen?

Update 1: This is true even if I change the pd.read_excel(engine='openpyxl')

Update 2: To clarify here are examples:

test.xlsm

[image: test.xlsm]

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsm', engine='openpyxl')

print(df)

df['Col_4'] = df['Col_3'].apply(lambda x: x*2)

wb = xl.load_workbook('test.xlsm')
ws = wb.active
df = df['Col_4'].to_frame()
rowsdf = dataframe_to_rows(df, index = False, header = False)
for row_indexdf, rowdf in enumerate(rowsdf, 2):
    for column_indexdf, valuedf in enumerate(rowdf, 4):
        ws.cell(row=row_indexdf, column = column_indexdf, value = valuedf)

wb.save('test.xlsm')
```

First time running:

```
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
0      1      6     11
1      2      7     12
2      3      8     13
```

Second time running:

```
   Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Unnamed: 3
0      1    NaN    NaN          22
1      2    NaN    NaN          24
2      3    NaN    NaN          26
```

Why are the second two columns now blank? I did not write over them...I do not think.

Comment: Why do you start at index 2 and 4 where you use `enumerate`?

Comment: Because I am trying to have it write into column D in Excel starting in D2 so the data lines up.

Comment: if you only need to write the data to col4, why are you iterating on all the columns here - "for column_indexdf, valuedf in enumerate(rowdf, 4):" ?

Comment: Figured out the issue, formula's aren't evaluated until excel is opened. Answer can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618659/11865956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `openpyxl` nor `pandas` evaluate excel formulas. Opening a file in `pandas` is equivalent to opening the file with `openpyxl` in `data_only=True` mode.

So here, when you save the file that you've written, a bunch of NaNs appear because excel never had the chance to evaluate the changed sheet.

Interesting enough, if you open the file with `openpyxl` and further investigate one of the NaN cells, the expected formula is still there!

Comment: And how to evaluate this formula and read values? Note: I don't have excel installed and I only want to read value

Comment: There is no value until it is evaluated by Excel/an Excel equivalent.